# Object initialization in Java - terminology

Tags: java

I came across [this](http://way2java.com/oops-concepts/reference-variables-anonymous-objects/) blog, and they used term **Anonymous object instantiation**

Is it really an "official term" or not?

In any case, what is the official terminology for that kind of code: calling a method without explicitly creating object with its name like in this example
(UPDATE: I am referring to explicitly giving a name to object not explicitly creating object)
:

```
public class Predictions3Client {
    public static void main(String[]  args) {
        new Predictions3Client().demo();
    }

    private void demo() {
        Localhost_Predictions3ResourcesP.Root root = Localhost_Predictions3ResourcesP.root();
        Localhost_Predictions3ResourcesP.Root.Xml xmlGetter = root.xml();
        String xml = xmlGetter.getAsXml(String.class); 
        System.out.println("The raw XML:\n" + xml);   
    }
}
```

```
new Predictions3Client().demo();
```

vs

```
Predictions3Client p3c = new Predictions3Client ();
p3c.demo();
```

I don't consider that as "method chaining" or "Fluent interface" as it is object related not method related.

Comment: "calling a method without explicitly creating object" that's not true in `new Predictions3Client().demo();`, an instance of `Predictions3Client` is created in both of your options

Comment: @RC."....without it's name" - I agree that the sentence is probably not clear but I was referring to explicitly giving NAME not creating object.

Comment: I don't think that it's an official term. Objects don't have names, so the term "anonymous" isn't appropriate. They can be assigned to variables, or not. In that case, the object that is constructed is not assigned to a variable.

Comment: I'm not sure it has an official name, or needs one.  I just call it "calling a method on a object".

Comment: Interesting search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%22Anonymous+object+instantiation%22

Comment: @RC Yes i read those two posts before one for JavaScript and one for Java and even there is one or two for C# and C++ but I asked because I found that blog.

Answer (score 0):

In Java Anonymous objects are objects that don't have class names or have abstract class names.  In short, you must fill in the "missing" methods to build the class, and those "missing" methods aren't tied to a class name.

```
   Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         System.out.println("Hi, I'm anonymous!");
      }
   }
```

is an example.  If it was a fully named class, it would look like

```
 public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {
      public void run() {
         System.out.println("Hi, I'm not anonymous, I'm a HelloRunnable!");
      }
 }
```

Note that anonymous classes are still constructed, but they are constructed with the missing methods as parameters (they're supplied between the curly braces).  So, technically you are still "creating" a class, and you are still "creating an instance" of a class, but that class has no single, uniquely identifiable class name.

Hence the "anonymous object instantiation" which I would have referred to by the simpler phrase "anonymous object creation"

Keep in mind that the first example's class name is not properly referred to as a "Runnable" class because not all runnables will print out "Hi, I'm anonymous" as demonstrated in the example below.

```
   Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         System.out.println("Hi, I'm anonymous!");
      }
   }
   runnable = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         System.out.println("Hi, I'm anonymous's cousin!");
      }
   }
```

However, in the example above, it is proper to call both classes a Runnable, because they both implement the runnable interface.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Sizik Ok, I understand how my question is a bit off the mark, but the point I was trying to make is that the term "Anonymous Object Instantiation" is already bound to a concept, and what is being asked above isn't that concept.  At best, I'd call the technique above "method call on a newly created object" but that's not a "proper" term, it's one I just made up.  Still it is clear, concise and less obscure than the grab bag of words that blog writer put together.